# dynamic path for file upload in jsp/servlet

Tags: jsp

How can I upload files based on the selection of combobox?
Example: there are two comboboxes namely year and dept. If I select year the file should be saved on the year folder in combination with dept.

Answer (score 0):

You may get real path for given `virtual` path using `ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)` method.

```
String virtualPath="2002/" + fileName;
String realPath=getServletContext().getRealPath(virtualPath);
```